# PHP cURL to get the Bing search result count

Tags: php, curl, search, count, bing

I have a PHP application and for last few years I'm using the PHP cURL to get the Bing search count results for given domain.

From the cURL result HTML, my program extracts the count. But now I noticed that cURL HTML is not returning the div with search count.

[image]

Do anyone know how to get the Bing search result count using cURL? If this method is impossible, any other way we can do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most search engine providers are not happy if you try to scrape their result pages, and will implement measures to try and prevent it. If you want any data from search engines - then you should use their APIs.

Comment: in addition to cbroe comment. you might break the law by violating their Term of Services, see [the MSA for sure](https://www.microsoft.com/en/servicesagreement/). in addition, you might having a lot of trouble as php curl didnt execute any javascrips that interacts with the DOM. you should really use [their APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-custom-search/overview) and consume their jsons.